# Is it possible to get referral data on client side with google analytics.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need to get referral information about current visitor on client side.
Is it possible to do with Google analytics.js or I need use some other extra library ?
I saw http://www.analyticsseo.com/blog/using-google-analytics-to-get-referral-and-user-activity/ but I can't get access to this on client side.

Comment: Your link refers to an older version of Google Analytics. With Universal Analytics information is processed serverside, so you can't anymore access cookies for information.

Comment: Is is possible to do in other way ?

Comment: As per Drazilis answer, you can read document.referrer on the landing page and save the value to your own cookie.  Realistically you cannot use data from Analytics for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of core JavaScript, actually.

```
string = document.referrer;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95229140

Comment: Thanks you, Yes I know it, I just inserting in Google API